# I can't manage to navigate thought different branches on my GIT project

Tags: git, branch

I'm working on my first GIT repo, which has several branches. Through the lesson, we have to switch between different branches.

At the moment , I've been cloning on Visual Code Studio the repo, which is working fine. The project opens normally on vscode.

When I try to switch branches, it doesn't work.
When I type : `git branch` it only shows me : `* main`.

However, there should be more branches on the project!
Here is the git link : https://github.com/OpenClassrooms-Student-Center/debuggez-l-interface-de-votre-site/tree/main

Comment: Did you try moving to another branch? Maybe it's just not present in your local machine. Try to move to the other branch using git checkout and it should be retrieved by git from the remote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When I type : git branch it only shows me : `* main`

By default `git branch` shows *local* branches.

When you fetch a repo, its branches start out as *remote* branches - they're still fetched, but start off only under `remotes/repo/branchname`.

- Run `git branch [--list] -r|--remote` to see these.

When you create a local branch that tracks a remote branch, as is done by default for `master -> remotes/origin/master` (or in your case for `main -> remotes/origin/main`), then you have a local branch.

- Run `git branch [--list]` to see these.

You want to see *all* branches:

- run `git branch [--list] -a|--all` to see everything.

When you checkout a local branch that doesn't already exist, but matches the name of a remote branch, it will be set up to track the remote correctly even though you couldn't see it when simply running `git branch`.

> When I try to switch branches, it doesn't work

But you *didn't* try to switch branches. You looked to see what branches existed (without realizing it only showed the local ones) and never actually ran `git checkout partie-1/chapitre-1/section-1` or whatever. Right?

You should feel relaxed about *trying* this even before you knew the above: you can always delete the branch again if something went wrong, and `checkout` failing has no side-effects whatsoever. If you mis-spell a branch name, it isn't going to ruin your repo or lose your work.

You should also get in the habit of checking the online documentation. Running `git help branch` shows all these options.

---

Sample output:

```
$ git branch
* main

$ git branch -r
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/partie-1/chapitre-1/section-1

$ git branch -a
* main
  remotes/origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main
  remotes/origin/partie-1/chapitre-1/section-1
```

---

PS. The reason for having both local and remote versions of the same branch is that they can diverge: you need to be able to fetch the remote version *without* altering your local copy, in order to compare them and decide what to do about it (usually merging or rebasing).

Comment: Thank you sir, you solved all the problem. I think I got now how to use properly git and VSC, I can navigate through all different sections correctly. Thank you so much community.

Comment: If the answer helped, you can mark it as accepted - currently this question still shows up as unsolved.

Comment: I'm so sorry, I will never let a question left like that when people nicely responded to it. Everything's clear now for me ! Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only see the `main` branch in your local clone your might want to do a [`git fetch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) to get all the other branches that exist in the remote repository.